# How to get the intersection of two arrays by keys?

Tags: php, arrays, arrayiterator

I want to save certain values from `$_POST` into a file. But I only want values where the key is in the array `$lang`.

As an example:

```
$_POST = [1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c"];
$lang = [2, 3];
```

With this input I would only want the values from `$_POST` where the key is in the `$lang` array.

Expected output would be:

```
[2 => "b", 3 => "c"]
```

Right now I'm trying to archive this using `ArrayIterator` and `MultipleIterator`, but this loops through both arrays:

```
$post = new ArrayIterator($_POST);
$lang_array = new ArrayIterator($lang); 
$it = new MultipleIterator;
$it->attachIterator($post);
$it->attachIterator($lang_array);
$fh = fopen('name.php', 'w');
foreach($it as $e) {
    fwrite($fh , $e[1] .'-' . $e[0] );
    fwrite($fh ,"\n" );   
}
```

So I'm a bit stuck how to solve this problem?

Comment: So you want to use the values from `$lang` as keys for `$_POST` ?

Comment: can you pl elobrate what you exectly need?

Comment: @Rizier123    no.  values from $_POST as keys for $lang

Comment: @DonLaknath Don't make it complicated, just do: `print_r(array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($lang)));`

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks. I'll try :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Way to go, thats not complicated at all! Hehehe

Comment: @DonLaknath Was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334201/php-how-to-combine-two-arrays#comment56409685_34334201 what you wanted?

Comment: @Rizier123 yeah its working :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// Combining both arrays into one.
$combined_array = array_merge($_POST, $lang);
$fh = fopen('name.php', 'w');
foreach($combined_array as $key => $value){
    fwrite($fh , $key .'-' . $value );
    fwrite($fh ,"\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the intersection of two arrays by keys you can use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php), but since the keys are values in `$lang` you just have to flip it first with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php), e.g.

```
print_r(array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($lang)));
```

Answer (score -1):

two Array combining please try this code:-

```
<?php
 $fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
 $age=array("35","37","43");
 $c=array_combine($fname,$age);
  print_r($c);
?>
```

and two array merge :-

```
<?php
$a1=array("red","green");
 $a2=array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>
```

this code is useful for two array combining and merge